# Calculating the average state occupation number of particles (in momentum space)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space

The average state occupation number of particles in the momentum space (I think "state" refers to a cell in the momentum space) is given by

$$\mathcal{N} = n\frac{(2\pi)^3}{\frac{4\pi}{3}(m\delta v)^3} \tag{1}$$

Here $n$ is the spatial number density of particles, $(2\pi)^3$ represents the volume of the tiniest cell in phase space, $\delta v$ is the velocity dispersion (standard deviation, I think) and $\frac{4\pi}{3}(m\delta v)^3$ represents the volume of the momentum sphere. Also,

$$n = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3p}{(2\pi)^3}f(\vec{x},\vec{p})$$
where $f$ is the distribution function which means it counts the number of particles in a phase space volume of $(2\pi)^3$. Please note here that $\hbar=1$.

How do I derive equation (1)? Also, why is $\delta v$ used instead of the average velocity?

Comment: Source for the formula?

Comment: https://link.aps.org/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.111301?casa_token=yk1tH8un5RQAAAAA:pf8ViM9cJBfh9U2RH8NdjWy7cXRr_19LbMxTtQhfbbXXk7i35oEKnSRSIN5Y_mTE39HaWcnaX9ONWRtJ
Look at equation (6)